# MPI Broadcast and Reduce

Tags: c, multiprocessing, mpi

I have this code below..
When I run this with `mpiexec -n 2`
I get output in the console log like `The input sequence is as follows: 0 1 2 3`
I'm trying to get an output sequence of `0 2 6 12`
which is an addition of `PartialResult` in the forloop
This is the result of the forloop, and I get this for each process, so when I run with 2 processes, this gets printed out twice.

```
Partial result in forloop: 0 
Partial result in forloop: 1 
Partial result in forloop: 3 
Partial result in forloop: 6
```

I want to add them so that the output sequence (when rank == 0), this return `0 2 6 12`. Can this be achieved after MPI_Reduce step?

Below is the entire C code.

```
int main(void)

{
    int my_rank, comm_sz;
    int i;
    int Count = 4;
    int Number[4];
    int PartialResult = 0;
    int Result;

    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);

    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &comm_sz);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);


    if(my_rank == 0)
    {
        printf("The input sequence is as follows: \n");

        for (i = 0; i < Count; i++)
        {
            Number[i] = i;
            printf("%d ", Number[i]);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }

    // Process 0 sends data to all of the processes
    MPI_Bcast(Number, Count, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    for (i = 0; i < Count; i++)
    {
        Number[i] += my_rank;
        PartialResult += Number[i];
        printf("\n");
        printf("Partial result in forloop: %d \n", PartialResult);

    }
    MPI_Reduce(&PartialResult, &Result, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_PROD, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    printf("partial result after reduce: %d \n", PartialResult);    

    // Print out the result 
    if (my_rank == 0) {
        printf("\n");
        for (i = 0; i < Count; i++) {
            printf("\n");
            printf("\n");
            printf("Result[i]: %d \n", Result[i]);

        } 
    }

    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: task `0` partial results are `{0,1,3.6}` and task `1` partial results are `{1,3,6,10}`. so what are you trying to achieve ? '{0,2,6,12}` does not make sense to me, are you expecting `{1,4,9,16}` instead ? in that case, use an array of partial results and `MPI_Reduce()` the full array.

Comment: I think if you make the Result into a int instead of an array it returns 0 1 3 6 for both tasks.. sorry that’s my bad.

Comment: Please edit your code if something has to be updated. You might also want to print the rank of each task (to make sure all your tasks do not have rank zero)

Comment: updated accordingly so both processors' output are `0 1 3 6`!

Comment: no they are **not**! first, have each task print `my_rank` and see  what happens...

Comment: You're right.. I don't understand why each processor is having different output.

Comment: because the output depends on `my_rank` (`Number[i] += my_rank;`)

Comment: I feel like such an idiot lol. Okay will be removing the `Number[i] += my_rank;` part to get the `0 1 3 6` and then with these result, you were suggesting to use `PartialResult[4]` and reduce using this `PartialResult` to pass to `MPI_Reduce`?

Comment: if you want to display `{1,2,6,12}`, you can reduce the entire array with the appropriate operator.